# Problem with simple coding for PLDuino: trying to turn relay on and off

Tags: programming, uploading, relay, compilation-errors

I am writing the following, simple code to try to turn a relay in the PLDuino on and off, and it is giving me warnings and not compiling/uploading. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <PLDuino.h>  
using namespace PLDuino;

void setup()  
{  
  // A necessary call.  
  // It sets pin modes according to their function.  
  PLDuino::init();  
}  

void loop()  
{  
  // Simple switch RELAY3 on and off with 2 second timeout.  
  digitalWrite(PLDuino::RELAY3, HIGH);  
  delay(2000);  
  digitalWrite(PLDuino::RELAY3, LOW);  
  delay(2000);  
}
```

I have installed the proper libraries. Here are the warnings I am getting:

```
WARNING: Category 'Graphics' in library PLDTouch is not valid. Setting to 'Uncategorized'
WARNING: Category 'General' in library PLDuino-Library is not valid. Setting to 'Uncategorized'
WARNING: Category 'Graphics' in library PLDuinoGUI is not valid. Setting to 'Uncategorized'
Sketch uses 1702 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8183 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM4": The system cannot find the file specified.


avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

Answer (score 1):

For the library warning, you'll need to add / edit library.properties to those folders to specify a valid category.

This is an example library.properties to give you a feel for the structure (I found this particular one [here](https://github.com/digitalloggers/PLDuino)).

```
name=TMRpcm_PLDuino
version=1.0
author=TMRh20
maintainer=digitalloggers
sentence=PCM/WAV Audio playback (USE_TIMER2 enabled)
paragraph=Play WAV audio files from SD card using AVR (UNO,Nano,etc) based devices.
category=Communication
url=https://github.com/digitalloggers/TMRpcm_PLDuino
architectures=avr
```

However, these are just warnings, and don't seem to be the cause of your problem.

---

Your actual problem in this case seems to be that it's trying to upload the sketch via COM4 and it can't find the PLDuino on that port.

Comment: Ok. So do you know how I can get it to find the PLDuino?

Comment: @CDDavis What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows computer